# error when compiling testfiles from installed c-algorithms library

Tags: c, gcc, header

I'm trying to install and test c library c-algorithms from Github.

https://github.com/fragglet/c-algorithms/blob/master/test/test-queue.c

When I try to test the installation from the generated test folder with:

`` gcc -o test-arraylist  `pkg-config --cflags --libs libcalg-1.0` test-arraylist.c ``

I get the following error massage:

`test-arraylist.c:30:23: fatal error: arraylist.h: No such file or directory 
compilation terminated.`

I use a Vagrant box: ubuntu/xenial32 with Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Prior to installation of c-algorithms: 
`sudo apt-get install autoconf` 
`sudo apt-get install libtool` 
`sudo apt-get install pkg-config`

To install the library I have done following:

`sudo ./autogen.sh` 
`sudo ./configure` 
`sudo make` 
`sudo make install`

Any help would be highly apriciated

Comment: and what's the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs libcalg-1.0`?

Comment: the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs libcalg-1.0` is:
`-I/usr/local/include/libcalg-1.0 -L/usr/local/lib -lcalg`

Comment: so, **is** there an `arraylist.h` in `/usr/local/include/libcalg-1.0`?

Comment: You only need sudo make install for the install. sudo for other commands is dangerous.

Comment: There is a arraylist.h in subfolder: `/usr/local/include/libcalg-1.0/libcalg` only `libcalg.h` in `/usr/local/include/libcalg-1.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test-arraylist.c has line `#include "arraylist.h"` but it is under the libcalg subdirectory not directly in the include path.

libcalg subdir should be added to the include path or you have to modify the include like `#include "libcalg/arraylist.h"`

If you want only run the tests, then run the 
`sudo make check` from the build root (in your case it is the source root)

Comment: With: ``gcc -o test-arraylist `pkg-config --cflags --libs libcalg-1.0` -I /usr/local/include/libcalg-1.0/libcalg test-arraylist.c`` the compiler can find the header files, still gets errors, but dont think they are related to this issue: ``/tmp/ccyupYo4.o: In function `test_arraylist_sort':
test-arraylist.c:(.text+0x166e): undefined reference to `arraylist_free'
/tmp/ccyupYo4.o: In function `main':
test-arraylist.c:(.text+0x16a3): undefined reference to `run_tests'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status``

Comment: This is why, because the test-arraylist.c is not able to compile itself.
You need the libcalgtest.a and libtestframework.a
the correct compilation command is:
`gcc -I../src -g -o test-arraylist test-arraylist.c ../src/libcalgtest.a libtestframework.a`

Comment: More simple way building test-arraylist is using make
`make test-arraylist`

Answer (score -1):

This is probably going to be stomped on by process-fetishizers.

But.

When you build in a Unix/Linux operating system (and derivatives like RTEMS), you are building off other people's libraries - so you need those libraries and their header files ( just like c-alg... ) installed in locations that your compiler can find.

To find a file that is associated with a package, use dpkg as explained here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file

But you have another problem you might not be aware of. You are trying to compile a test program using a gcc command when the software uses GNU autoconf automake and probably libtool to function PROPERLY.

**Perhaps you don't understand you need to make sure autoconf, automake, and then libtool find the right configuration from one directory system to another. Fedora puts files in differing spots from Ubuntu distros.**

Instead run:

```
autoreconf -fvi
```

first in the top level directory and see if this finds your header file.

**THEN** you run

```
./configure
```

and then

```
make test/check
```

(whichever it uses, some use recipe "all-tests", etc.)

make all

This would make all if your system is ready to handle them.

Comment: When I do the configuration this way, pkg-config dont get setup correctly: ``Package libcalg-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcalg-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcalg-1.0' found
test-arraylist.c:30:23: fatal error: arraylist.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.``

Comment: Ok. but this is a smaller problem - now autotools knows where to look.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/210210/pkg-config-path-environment-variable

Comment: use export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig to tell compiler where pkg-config install .pc files.

Comment: Any luck  compiling?

Comment: Not right now, would would exspect to see a .pc in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` but the folder is empty

Comment: I just downloaded and compiled using my method and the include path misses the libcalg subfolder.

Comment: Probably same with -L command.  This found the header file and library: gcc -o test-arraylist -I/usr/local/include/libcalg-1.0/libcalg test-arraylist.c  -L/usr/local/lib -lcalg

Comment: gcc -o test-arraylist -I/usr/local/include/libcalg-1.0/libcalg test-arraylist.c  -L/usr/local/lib -lcalg    
/tmp/ccvAEeDs.o: In function `test_arraylist_new_free':
test-arraylist.c:(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `alloc_test_set_limit'
test-arraylist.c:(.text+0x171): undefined reference to `alloc_test_set_limit'
/tmp/ccvAEeDs.o: In function `test_arraylist_append':
...
/tmp/ccvAEeDs.o: In function `main':
test-arraylist.c:(.text+0x18a8): undefined reference to `run_tests'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: so now all you need to do is find this alloc_test_limit() library function.

Comment: Now i got the same results as you, just needed to do the `make` and `make install` c-algorithms folder.